# What is the fastest way to implement the find first set algorithm in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, bit-manipulation, algorithm

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set), a find first algorithm is:

> a bit operation that, given an unsigned machine word, designates the index or position of the least significant bit set to one in the word counting from the least significant bit position.

This is also known as the "count trailing zeros" algorithm. What is the fastest way to implement it in Solidity?